# Почему не удаётся изменить размер виджета в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

По какой-то причине используя `QLayout` не получается изменить размер кнопок.

В своей программе использую `Lay Out in a Grid`, но кнопки слишком маленькие при его использовании, можно ли как-то увеличить их размер?

Ответ нужен именно для *Qt Designer*, т.к. пока делаю заготовку и хотелось бы всё сделать через него.

**proba.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>801</width>
      <height>191</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Предпросмотр</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Добавить</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Удалить</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="3">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Увеличить</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: покажите пример `.ui` файла

Comment: @S.Nick, завтра скину пример

Comment: @S.Nick, `.ui` файл можете скачать по ссылке: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17hfBIIcFjP3uu8o0ElbjzgQucUn3N17N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не заметил где вы используете `Lay Out in a Grid`.

> **minimumSize : QSize**
>
> Это свойство содержит минимальный размер виджета. 
>   Размер виджета нельзя изменить до меньшего размера, чем минимальный размер виджета. 
>   Размер виджета устанавливается на минимальный размер, если текущий размер меньше. 
>   Минимальный размер, установленный этой функцией, переопределит минимальный размер, 
>   определенный QLayout. 
>   Чтобы сбросить минимальный размер, используйте значение QSize(0, 0).
>
> **maximumSize : QSize**
>
> Это свойство содержит максимальный размер виджета в пикселях 
>   Размер виджета нельзя изменить до размера, превышающего максимальный размер виджета. 
>   По умолчанию это свойство содержит размер, в котором ширина и высота имеют значения 16777215.
>
> Класс **QSizePolicy** - это атрибут макета, описывающий политику горизонтального 
>   и вертикального изменения размера.
>
> Каждый виджет возвращает QSizePolicy, 
>   который описывает политику горизонтального и вертикального изменения размера, 
>   которую он предпочитает при разметке. 
>   Вы можете изменить это для определенного виджета, изменив его свойство QWidget::sizePolicy.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


baseUIClass, baseUIWidget = uic.loadUiType("proba_1.ui")


class Example(baseUIWidget, baseUIClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**proba_1.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>456</width>
    <height>499</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(166, 171, 255);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Предпросмотр</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Добавить</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="2">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Удалить</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="3">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>150</width>
           <height>100</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Увеличить</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(164, 255, 213);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>456</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я использовал Layout в Frame, где кнопки находятся. Чуть позже проверю ваш вариант, если заработает, то помечу как решение

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, изменил в `sizePolicy` все параметры на `ignore` и смог изменять размер кнопок